# Succulent with green/red leaves, small and multiple pink flowers, identification

Tags: identification, flowers, succulents

I've already asked here but the none of the answer were correct and the picture I uploaded was without the flowers. It likes partial sun/bright shade. Does anyone know what succulent is this?

[image]

[image]